# Laravel 5.5 MethodNotAllowed on update using PUT method

Tags: rest, laravel-routing, php-7.1, laravel-5.5

I have a problem with updating data in Laravel 5.5. When I am trying to update record of resource controller, I am getting `MethodNotAllowedException`, but I am using `PUT` method. Here are details:

Routes:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function(){
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index')->name('home')

    Route::resource('stages', 'StagesController');

});
```

Form:
[image]

Ajax method:

```
$('#ajax_form_modal').on('submit', 'form', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $modal = $('#ajax_form_modal');
    var $modal_dialog = $modal.find('.modal-dialog');
    var $form = $(this);
    var method = 'post';

    if ($form.find('[name="_method"]')) {
        method = $form.find('[name="_method"]').val(); //this fires
    } else if ($form.has('method')) {
        method = $form.attr('method');
    }

    //method = 'PUT'

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        dataType: 'json',
        type: method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
```

Response:

```
"trace": [
    {
        "file": "\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection.php",
        "line": 238,
        "function": "methodNotAllowed",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection",
        "type": "->",
        "args": [
            [
                "GET",
                "HEAD",
                "POST"
            ]
        ]
    },
```

Route:List:
[image]

I have no idea, why update method allows only 'GET','HEAD','POST', i tried to handle update manually using Post method and it works, also tried to debug place where route mismatch happens but no luck. Can anyone advise something? I really don't want to broke RESTFUL of my controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I find out the bug: href should be action, need more sleep...

```
$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    dataType: 'json',
    type: method,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
```